# How to filter aws log using metric filter DescribeMetricFiltersResult using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to get aws metric filter logs on the basis of group name but I keep getting this error

> Failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [.-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+

Code Snippet:

```
    AWSLogs log;
    String group-name="xyz"

    DescribeMetricFiltersRequest describeMetricFiltersRequest = new DescribeMetricFiltersRequest(group-name); 
    DescribeMetricFiltersResult res1 = log.describeMetricFilters(describeMetricFiltersRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

If using the AWS SDK 2.0 you should use the builder pattern to construct the request:

```java
return DescribeMetricFiltersRequest.builder()
            .logGroupName("xyz")
            .build();
```